# Raise default browser and get the url

Tags: java, browser, process, runtime

I know that using process or processbuilder class in java I can start application.

On windows, all i need is to open a default browser with the url that I specify and get the returned url from the browser back to java program. Think like I am getting url to get access token from facebook. How can I do this?

Comment: You can access the Windows Registry to get the default browser(and may be the default browser url too).

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. But how can I get the url from browser to my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is perhaps a very little known API called [java.awt.Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) that allows launching of default applications on many platforms. Using it to launch the default web browser with a URL is easy:

```
if ( Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported( Action.BROWSE ) ) {
   URI google = new URI( "http://www.google.com" );
   Desktop.getDesktop().browse( google );
}
```

Comment: That helps me. Thanks Strelok.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to get only the response of a specific URL there is no need to launch the browser, all you have to do is to use the [httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) library from apache, return the result and parse it accordingly.